# How to add an event receiver to my console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I have a simple console application that upload a file to sharepoint and then I do some operations with file that I need to do. Until now everything seems to be correct. But now I need to add an event receiver that when the file is update or deleted the event send a message to service bus indicating the change. I saw a lot of tutorials but none of them show how to do this from the beginning and using console application in c#, I need to know where to start.
PS: I am using VS 2013

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+create+custom+event - play with what you find and if you get stuck on something specific, share the code you're using and the error you're getting and we'll be here to help. Good luck! PS - if you want to trigger the event by  a file change rather than fire it yourself once done uploading, check out https://www.google.com/search?q=cgoogle&ie=&oe=#q=cgoogle+c-sharp+filesystemwatcher

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the fast answer...

Comment: Monitoring for local file edit/removal is the same in a console app as it is a windows app.. what specifically are you struggling with

Comment: (hint) the first result of the search link I posted (an MSDN article) contains three different examples of what you need - all already done for "console app format."